# While using python-flask, even after setting my environemnt to development mode it shows Environmeent:production in my Anaconda command prompt

Tags: python, flask, command-prompt, development-environment, production-environment

> This is my command prompt message showing the environment

(base) C:\Python\flask\url-shortener>set FLASK_APP = app.py

(base) C:\Python\flask\url-shortener>set FLASK_ENV = development

(base) C:\Python\flask\url-shortener>flask run
 * **Environment: production**
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

> This is my app.py code

from flask import Flask

hello = Flask(**name**)

@hello.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello Flask!'

Comment: Write code in code block. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it without the spaces around `=`

```
> set FLASK_APP=app.py
> set FLASK_ENV=development
```

Now try to start the server. It should work!